# Get lists of ID's and add on database using LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, linq, entity-framework

I have this method:

```
public ActionResult Complete(int id)
{
    // Validate customer owns this order
    bool isValid = storeDB.Orders.Any(
        o => o.OrderId == id &&
        o.Username == User.Identity.Name);

   bool CheckOrderValue = storeDB.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderId == id && o.Total == 0);
   int musicaID = storeDB.OrderDetails.Where(o => o.OrderId == id).Select(o => o.MusicaId).FirstOrDefault();

    if (isValid && CheckOrderValue)
    {
        int idUser = 0;
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var membership = (WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
            idUser = membership.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
        }

        var musicas = storeDB.Musicas.Where(x => x.MusicaId == musicaID)
                                     .Select(x => new { x.Nome, x.NomeArtista, x.genero, x.path })
                                     .ToList().First();

        var y = new UsuarioMusica()
        {
            UserId = idUser,
            MusicaId = musicaID,
            GeneroId = musicas.genero.GeneroId,
            genero = musicas.genero,
            Nome = musicas.Nome,
            NomeArtista = musicas.NomeArtista,
            path = musicas.path
        };
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            storeDB.UsuarioMusicas.Add(y);
            storeDB.SaveChanges();

        }

        return View(id);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

I want to take a list of id's on this line:

```
int musicaID = storeDB.OrderDetails.Where(o => o.OrderId == id)
                                   .Select(o => o.MusicaId).FirstOrDefault();
```

And after this, I need to add each ID to the database.

I think that I need to make a `foreach` with the list `musicaID`, but I don't know how I'll pass each ID to add to the database.

Actually, the method is adding only the first element, I know why, is because the `FirstOrDefault` method.

How can I change this to add more than one ID?

Comment: Do you have a table that only contains a column for the IDs, or do you have items with IDs that you need to add to a table?

Comment: In the table orderDetails, have the column OrderDetailId, OrderId and MusicaId, where each order can have more than one music, so the OrderDetail table do the relationship of order and music table, understand?

Comment: Currently, if an order have two music added, I'm only adding the first music on database, and the second is not added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use foreach loop and save your changes when all the elements will be added. For example in this way:

```
public ActionResult Complete(int id)
{
    // Validate customer owns this order
    bool isValid = storeDB.Orders.Any(
        o => o.OrderId == id &&
        o.Username == User.Identity.Name);

    bool CheckOrderValue = storeDB.Orders.Any(o => o.OrderId == id && o.Total == 0);

    if (isValid && CheckOrderValue)
    {
        int idUser = 0;
        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var membership = (WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;
            idUser = membership.GetUserId(User.Identity.Name);
        }

        var musicaIDs = storeDB.OrderDetails.Where(o => o.OrderId == id).Select(o => o.MusicaId).ToList();

        foreach (var musicaId in musicaIDs)
        {
            var musicas = storeDB.Musicas.Where(x => x.MusicaId == musicaId)
                .Select(x => new { x.Nome, x.NomeArtista, x.genero, x.path }).ToList().First();

            var y = new UsuarioMusica()
            {
                UserId = idUser,
                MusicaId = musicaID,
                GeneroId = musicas.genero.GeneroId,
                genero = musicas.genero,
                Nome = musicas.Nome,
                NomeArtista = musicas.NomeArtista,
                path = musicas.path
            };

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                storeDB.UsuarioMusicas.Add(y);
            }
        }

        storeDB.SaveChanges();

        return View(id);
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to do exactly what OP is suggesting. +1 (provided that he's articulated his problem correctly which is dubious).  This could probably be optimized by combining the musicaIDs query with the musicas query and looping over that.

Comment: Thanks @PawelMaga, only need to change in your solution the int musicaIDs to List<int> musicaIDs

Comment: Ahh, sorry, I did not notice this line. @paqogomez I agree with that it can be done in many other ways, but this was not related to the question.

Comment: @PedroHenrique Glad you found your answer, Pawal did an excellent job.  I was simply suggesting an optimization which was why it was a comment not an answer. :)